# Website redirects me to https://www.www.website.com name when typing url https://website.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cloudflare

I do not know or understand why my website redirects me with two "www". I was enabling CloudFlare through Bluehost, which is my provider and all of a sudden the URL stopped working and previously https://website.com worked.

I know that cloudflare requires the use of www. in the URL. So I assume the process of adding and removing it caused some issues.

Any help resolving my issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can guess that as Bluehost requires use of www with Cloudflare, now, maybe, your "main" domain name is www.website.com and your old "rule" just add another www to your domain name. So, Check Bluehost admin panel for redirect rules and disable redirect to www.

Also, maybe, You can disable Cloudfare in Bluehost, create your own Cloudflare account and change your name servers.

Comment: Sounds totally plausible. I was believing that something like this happened as well. Could it have something to do with my DNS settings? I know that bluehost changed them when I was using Cloudflare.